# Error while filehandling in Blender using Python

Tags: python, arduino, blender

I'm trying to read data in [Blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29) from an external device connected to an [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) and save onto a file. But it gives this error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Python script error from controller "contr#CONTR#1":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SerialBGE.py", line 6, in <module>
    f=open('abc.dat', 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.dat'
```

My code is correct, and I don't understand the problem.

`serial.py`:

```
import GameLogic
import pickle
import os

os.system('dane.py')
f=open('abc.dat', 'r')
print "abc.dat = "
x=pickle.load(f)
print x
print "end of abc.dat"
f.close();
y=x[:]
for z in x:
    y.remove(z)
    print "removing " + str(z)
    print str(y) + " and " + str(x)
    f=open('abc.dat', 'w')
    pickle.dump(y, f)
    f.close()
    contr = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
    location=contr.actuators["loc"]
    y = 0.001*(ord(z)-128)
    location.dLoc=[y,0,0]
    contr.activate(location)
```

dane.py:

```
import serial
import pickle

with serial.Serial(COM3,9600) as port, open('abc.dat','r') as f:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        x = port.read(size=1)
        y=pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        f=open('abc.dat','w')
        for i in x:
            y.append(i)
        pickle.dump(y,f)
        f.close()
port.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error because the file 'abc.dat' doesn't exist the first time you run the program.

You need to handle the initial case, when you run the program for the first time, before 'abc.dat' exists.

Comment: So m reading, appending then writing the final data. In that case my code is fine. And it works fine when I put my own data instead of the port.read() .

Comment: That's fine, but think about your structure:  you read the file, add the new data, and write it back out.  But what happens when you run it for the FIRST time?  The file doesn't exist to read from -- you need to handle that case.